# return value of a key in multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose there is a two dimensional array like this:

```
$rates = [
        ['id' => 'd', 'title' => 'dollar', 'sign' => '$'],
        ['id' => 'r', 'title' => 'rial', 'sign' => 'ریال'],
        ['id' => 't', 'title' => 'toman', 'sign' => 'T']
]
```

And I have a variable named $rate like this :

```
$rate = 'd';
```

Now I want simply get value of `title` of array that it's `id` is same `$rate` value. in this case `dollar`.

I know that we can search through the arrays in main array But I look for an easier way like `$rates[????][title]`.

What is best approach ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you converted it to use the `id` as the key using `array_column`, you can access from then on the way your after...

```
$rates = [
        ['id' => 'd', 'title' => 'dollar', 'sign' => '$'],
        ['id' => 'r', 'title' => 'rial', 'sign' => 'ریال'],
        ['id' => 't', 'title' => 'toman', 'sign' => 'T']
]
$rates = array_column($rates,null,'id');

echo $rates['d']['title'];
```

Gives...

```
dollar
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) is the best way, if you want to avoid a loop.

You could also transform the array or create a search function which would allow you to pick out what you want based upon what you pass it

For example: in `$rates` get `title` where `id` equals `d`

```
<?php
$rates = [
        ['id' => 'd', 'title' => 'dollar', 'sign' => '$'],
        ['id' => 'r', 'title' => 'rial', 'sign' => 'ریال'],
        ['id' => 't', 'title' => 'toman', 'sign' => 'T']
];

$rates = function ($key, $where, $equals) use ($rates) {
    return $rates[array_search($equals, array_column($rates, $where))][$key];
};

echo $rates('title', 'id', 'd');        // dollar
echo $rates('sign', 'id', 'd');         // $
echo $rates('sign', 'title', 'dollar'); // $
```

https://3v4l.org/KrN5b